# How can I set a value in core_config_data with Magento 2 programmatically?

Tags: magento2, core-config-data

I know you can set config data in Magento 1 with:

```
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('my/path/whatever', $value);
```

and you can get config data in Magento 2 with:

```
protected $_scopeConfig

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig) {
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}
```

+

```
$this->_scopeConfig->getValue( 'path/of/config', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE );
```

But I can't figure out, how I can save config data in Magento 2

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is how you should save data in magento2 core_config_data

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface

/**
 *  @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface
 */
protected $configWriter;

/**
 * @param WriterInterface $configWriter
 */
public function __construct(
    ....
    WriterInterface $configWriter
    .....
) {
    $this->configWriter = $configWriter;
}
```

**add below line in your calling method:**

```
$this->configWriter->save('my/path/whatever',  $value, $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeId = 0);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can Inject ConfigInterface class and use it to save the value.

```
protected $_configInterface;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigResource\ConfigInterface $configInterface
) {
    $this->_configInterface = $configInterface;
}
```

Then you can use it in your method like

```
$this->_configInterface
    ->saveConfig('section/group/field', $value, 'default', 0);
```

Comment: Do not do this except you are sure your paths don't need to be trimmed. It is recommended to use the configWriter